# Own pip python package import doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm currently trying to create my first python package. Sadly I'm running into some errors. Im just trying to define a few classes that should be importable.

Heres my folder structure

```
/pip-blitz-query
    /blitzjs_query
        __init__.py
        blitz.py
        blitz_http.py
        ...
    setup.py
```

Heres the error that occures when I try to import the class `Blitz` from `blitzjs_query`:

```
>>> import blitzjs_query
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\blitzjs_query\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blitz import Blitz
ImportError: No module named 'blitz'
```

Heres my `__init__.py` file:

```
from blitz import Blitz
from connection import Connection
from blitz_queue import Queue
from blitz_socket import Socket
from blitz_http import Http
```

And finally here is my `setup.py` file. I've tried different variations of the `__init__.py` file, and some with nothing at all in it - but it just never works

```
# Always prefer setuptools over distutils
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
# To use a consistent encoding
from codecs import open
from os import path

# Get the long description from the README file
here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
with open(path.join(here, 'README.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    name='blitzjs_query',

    version='0.0.2',

    description='HTTP/Socket.io adapter for the blitz.js framework',
    long_description=long_description,

    url='https://github.com/nexus-devs/pip-blitz-query',

    author='Nexus Devs',
    author_email='nexus@nexus-stats.com',

    license='MIT',

    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 1 - Planning',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',

        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
    ],

    keywords='development blitz nexus socket.io http',

    packages=find_packages(),

    install_requires=['pymitter', 'socketIO-client', 'promise', 'requests'],
)
```

Comment: Relative imports have to be explicit: `from .blitz import Blitz`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you use relative imports (prepend the submodule with one or multiple `.`):

```
from .blitz import Blitz
from .connection import Connection
from .blitz_queue import Queue
from .blitz_socket import Socket
from .blitz_http import Http
```

Because you don't create a module named `blitz` but only a **sub**module `blitzjs_query.blitz`.

You can refer to [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for more informations about relative and absolute imports:

> Guido has Pronounced that relative imports will use leading dots. A single leading dot indicates a relative import, starting with the current package. Two or more leading dots give a relative import to the parent(s) of the current package, one level per dot after the first. [...]

Answer (score 0):

Your module is named `blitzjs_query`, so prefix all your imports with `blitzjs_query.`

Like this:

```
from blitzjs_query.blitz import Blitz
from blitzjs_query.connection import Connection
from blitzjs_query.blitz_queue import Queue
from blitzjs_query.blitz_socket import Socket
from blitzjs_query.blitz_http import Http
```